# Ingresar valor en un campo de un registro MVC

Tags: c#, mvc

> ¿Cómo puedo recoger la asignacionID recién creada y guardarlo en el Campo AsignacioneID que hay en mi Tabla de empleados?

---

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AsignacionesID,MaterialesID,CantidadMaterial")] Asignacione asignacione,int EmpleadoID)
            {
                string error;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        db.Asignaciones.Add(asignacione);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        //Añadir asignación al IDEmpleado

                        var asignar = db.Employees
                            .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == EmpleadoID)
                            .Select(x=>x.AsignacionesID);

                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no sabemos lo suficiente sobre tu base de datos.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si en el mapping de la entidad defines la propiedad como `primary key` y ademas el campo es `identity` esta recibe el valor que se genera cuando insertas de forma automatica

```
class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var asignacion = modelBuilder.Entity<Asignacion>();
        asignacion.Property(x => x.AsignacioneID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

en este caso uso `fluent` para definir el mapping y el campo es identity o sea autoincremental

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AsignacionesID,MaterialesID,CantidadMaterial")] Asignacione asignacione,int EmpleadoID)
{
    string error;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Asignaciones.Add(asignacione);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var empleado = db.Employees
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == EmpleadoID);

            if(empleado != null)
            {
                empleado.AsignacioneID  = asignacione.AsignacioneID;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

puedes obtener el empleado por su id y asignarle a este el id que se creo de la asignacion

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar!! Voy a probarlo

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro con eso ya ha funcionado :)